# Protect python files from being changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

There is a scenario: the python script needs to be placed under `/home/my_user_name/bin` for other users to use.
But sometimes it appears that a user changes this file by mistake. Is there any best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: Change the permissions. Let others execute but not read and write.

Comment: Why don't you make your code into a python package? Then other users can `pip install` it and then just `import` what they need?

Comment: Proper OS file permissions aside, would it be enough to abort the script if it did not hash correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of /home/username is that the user can install/change stuff in there.

If it should not be changeable, install it somewhere else, such as `/usr/local/bin`, which the executable bit set on it `chmod +x`

Comment: Putting it in `/usr/local/bin` doesn't make it immutable; dropping its write permissions does. `chmod +x,-w`.

Answer (score 2):

Change [the permission bits so only you can write into it, but everyone can read and execute](https://chmod-calculator.com/).

```
chmod 755 /home/my_user_name/bin/script.py
```